# unhandled errors in php

Tags: php, error-handling

How can I know during runtime that my code threw a Warning?

example

```
try {
    echo (25/0);
} catch (exception $exc) {
    echo "exception catched";
}
```

throws a "Warning: Division by zero" error that i can not handle on my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the function [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Check out the sample code in the manual.

Make sure that you don't only suppress the error warnings, but instead silently redirect them to a log file or something similar. (This helps you track down bugs)

Comment: In going off what @svens said, error suppression for turning off all errors is done with `error_reporting(0)` See http://us.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: .. or by prepending an '@' to the command. Btw. the error handler will also be called when error_reporting is set to zero (with errno=0). The error handler is very handy and can be used to do things like final logging of time, parameters, memory usage, etc and notify the admin (for fatal errors). I don't wanted to recommend suppressing errors :).

Answer (score 5):

You need to handle the exception yourself as follows.e.g

```
function inverse($x)
{
    if(!$x)
    {
         throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else
    { 
        return 1/$x;
    }
}


try
{
     echo inverse(5);
     echo inverse(0);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: the purpose of exceptions is not to "prevent" errors from happening, like you do, but to provide a way of handling them _when_ they happen. Still, +1 for trying.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install an error handler that converts old style php "errors" into exceptions. See an example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)